# Why is there no 'cake watch:ios:dev'?

Tags: ios, cordova, brunch, hybrid-mobile-app

I am using [cordova-brunch](https://github.com/jupl/cordova-brunch) in a project and I would really like to not have to re-run the `cake build:ios:dev` command each time I modify the JavaScript/CoffeScript source. Even more since I usually have to also make changes in the iOS Objective-C code for my hybrid app and I generally rebuild the App from XCode forgetting to rebuild the JS/CS part.

The behaviour is identical for Chapless Brunch and Cider Brunch, but I still don't get what prevents a `cake watch:ios:dev` functionality. The available `cake watch:cordova:dev` doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Hey, I have reported a feature request for this here: https://github.com/jupl/cordova-brunch/issues/5

Comment: Thanks Paul ! I was not sure to do so by myself, since I found it "so obvious" that this would be cool